# Setting PHP settings in Zend Framework 2

Tags: php, zend-framework2

I'm working myself through creating an app using Zend Framework 2 and one of the features I really liked was having the ability to set PHP settings based on the environment (mostly enabling the error displays in the devel environment).  As far as I can tell from [my limited research](http://www.zfdaily.com/2012/04/configuring-php-settings-in-zf2/) this feature doesn't yet (or won't) exist and you have to create a custom solution for it.

Am I wrong or is this the only solution as of ZF 2.0.2?

Comment: Personally I like the solution put forward in the article, as you can simply add that module (PhpSettings) to your project for the desired functionality. I'm not sure if there is any benefit of having this hardwired into the framework.

Comment: I know a lot has changed between beta 4 and now and I didn't want to duplicate something that already exists in the Framework.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You're correct, as of 2.0.2, there is no "built-in" solution for this in ZF2. If you're using PHP config files, you can simply put the ini_set() calls there. I've outlined methods for doing environment specific configuration files on my blog: http://blog.evan.pro/environment-specific-configuration-in-zend-framework-2

At a quick glance, the solution on the link you provided should still work as of 2.0.2. Personally, I'd just put the ini_set() calls in my configs, as I said, instead of attaching an extra listener to the bootstrap event, an extra check for the config key, and a foreach loop, but that's the beauty of ZF2: If you're looking for an easy way to provide PHP settings via the config, there's a module for that!

Comment: To clarify, we've discussed re-adding this functionality on at least a couple of occasions, but there's just never enough reason to justify coding it into the framework since it's so trivial to just do it yourself.

Comment: Thank you.  I know version 2 is really new so the documentation really isn't there yet but it's made it hard for me going from 1 to 2 given how much has changed. :-)

Comment: Scott -- I understand the difficulty! That said, the reason for new major versions is typically because of a desire to break backwards compatibility in order to address shortcomings in the previous version. As such, yes, lots of new stuff to learn -- but you'll also be able to do many things you couldn't before. :)